# Python not recognised as command when using gitlab runner

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set up continuous integration on a gitlab repository.

I have added the following `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
 - test


test:
 image: python:3.7
 script:
  - python -v
 tags:
  - python
```

On gitlab, in settings->CI / CD, I have followed the instructions in 'Set up a specific Runner manually'. During the step 'please enter the executor:', I entered 'shell'.

When I try to commit the above `yml` file, the runner starts running, although it then gives the following error message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.9.2 (fa86510e)
  on wsf-1102 HUx_zvP8
Using Shell executor...
Running on WSF-1102...
DEPRECATION: this GitLab server doesn't support refspecs, gitlab-runner 12.0 will no longer work with this version of GitLab
Fetching changes...
Clean repository
From [my_repo]
   e327c9f..2f0e41f  [my_branch]-> origin/[my_branch]
Checking out 2f0e41f1 as [my_branch]...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ python -v
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 9009
```

How should I properly write the `yml` file, so that I can use `python` as a command to later run a `test.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is not in the runner is inside your docker image.
 inside the runner context, you don't have python installed to confirm this 
first test that python is properly installed in your terminal path.
then, start with [shell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) executer only for debugging before using and docker  image

try to run this command

```
gitlab-runner exec shell test
```

on this simple **.gitlab-ci.yml** (put the file **inside your git repo folder** )

```
stages:
 - test


test:
 script:
  - python -v
```

then try to work with the python image
when you want to use this image you need to specify you want to run with docker runner after you test the above cases 
run again on your local machine

```
gitlab-runner exec docker test
```

if you still dosent figure it out try following this guide
https://substrakt.com/journal/how-to-debug-gitlab-ci-builds-locally/